# Is it possible to get WPF to render low resolution fullscreen on a high res monitor?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, .net-core, rendering

I have a relatively large and complex application, and it uses about 700mb of memory on a 1080p monitor. This runs fine on most machines. On a  2160p (4k) monitor the ram usage quadruples, processor usage increases significantly and the gpu pretty much maxes out on anything short of a gaming rig.

I could spend a lot of time refactoring for small performance gains here and there, and I may have to do that regardless. However it seems useful to at least consider the possibility of rendering in 1080p on a 2160p monitor. There is no sensible reason for the application to require so many pixels.

Does anyone know how to do this? I know that it might involve the resolution independence functionality, or perhaps the zoom feature. I am not familiar enough with how the render pipeline works at this low level to really evaluate or even formulate a workaround for this.

For further detail, it is worth noting that there are a few currently open bugs regarding similar problems and there may actually be a fundamental flaw in one or more libraries that needs to be addressed.

e.g.

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3626

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4265

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3135

Update:

Update 2: Removed profiling data, I diagnosed the issue in this case and it had nothing to do with the one I was asking about in this question.

Comment: What exactly is it you are rendering? As far as I'm aware there is no simple property for this. There can be situation where it is useful render to a intermediate buffer, but I would use that as a last resort. Have you done any profiling to confirm that it is no other part of the program that is to blame?

Comment: Is your app bitmap image heavy? Very bizarre that your app would take up so much RAM even on a 4k monitor if you're mostly doing vector graphics. If you do have images though you can lower the resolution at the image source level which might help. But yeah we'd need to first figure out what exactly you're rendering that is causing this.

Comment: Also how are you determining ram usage? Task manager or visual studio profiler? Task manager - I BELIEVE - is including VRAM usage which you really have little control over but also shouldn't be a concern. Stuff is going on there at the Direct3D level. Also I hate to suggest this cause I know what it entails but have you considered porting to WinUI3?  A more modern compositing framework might do better.

Comment: Yes the app has bitmaps and also video playback. The bitmaps are pretty low resolution but the videos are 720p. Only one video is ever on screen at a time (using the WPF MediaElement). Ram usage was determined in both the profiler and the task manager to be sure. Yes WinUI3 would almost certainly have improved performance but that is not currently possible.

I will do some additional profiling and report back, from these comments it appears that there is no easy solution here.

Comment: Yeah I feel your pain. Does the profiler tell you the ram usage is mostly native or managed? Native would probably mostly be D3D surfaces which will be hard to address. Managed might be more manageable (har har).

Comment: Remember when you play video regardless of original resolution the CPU and/or GPU have to scale it up to the window resolution. So you've got basically 4K video output which is 33MB per frame. Cause remember it's got to use an in memory surface to composite into the visual tree. Video players also usually hold a frame buffer several frames in advance. So you could easily have 10 30MB D3D surfaces in RAM or VRAM at any given time.

Comment: Sorry to obsess but video playback is one of my passions. As far as CPU goes you don't know if your graphics card has a maximum D3D surface size smaller than the resolution of your video window. In that case D3D will fallback to RAM and CPU. Ugh! Plus, WPF uses D3D9. Newer graphics cards might have poor or no hardware D3D9 support anymore. So yeah there are dozens of possible reasons for this. Sorry you can't port to WinUI3. I feel your pain!

Comment: @PeterMoore I actually deal with a lot of video playback/encoding optimising questions in this application, would you be interested in sharing contact details? Is it possible to send a pm or something on SO?

Also I added some more data to the original question

Comment: HAH I don't think there is a PM function actually. But that first Github issue you linked to (3626) plagued me for years until I 100% did my main window from scratch. Performance improved dramatically. It has to do with WPF using D3D and maximized windows slightly spilling over onto the 2nd monitor. BIG oversight in the original WPF. If your issue goes away when using only 1 monitor, or resizing your window to be even SLIGHTLY less than full screen solves your problem then this is the culprit and I can offer some code on here that could help you do what I did.